# How to set Build ID of a elf file in Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

I recently need to set specific build-id to a elf file in Android.

Firstly,I use shell command like this:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -pie -Wl,--build-id=0xFFFFFFFF --sysroot /home/chengyi/code/android_6.0.1_bullhead/prebuilts/ndk/9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm main.c
```

`readelf -n a.out`.everthing is OK.

Above is only a demo,I need to set build-id in Android.mk at last.here is my Android.mk:

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        main.cpp


    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
        liblog \
        libdl \


    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/ \
        bionic \

    LOCAL_MODULE:= a.out

    LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := \
        -pie -Wl,--build-id=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF --sysroot /home/chengyi/code/android_6.0.1_bullhead/prebuilts/ndk/9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm \

    include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

The output elf file has a constant build-id,no matter how I strive.
Is there any method to set a specific build-id to elf file in Android.mk?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set build-id by Android.mk. Don't use variable `LOCAL_CXXFLAGS` or `LOCAL_CFLAGS`.

build-id is sent to linker,so you need to use `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` like this:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--build-id=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```